# How to specify a default bean for autowiring in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I am coding both a library and service consuming this library. I want to have a `UsernameProvider` service, which takes care of extracting the username of the logged in user. I consume the service in the library itself:

```
class AuditService {
  @Autowired
  UsernameProvider usernameProvider;

  void logChange() {
    String username = usernameProvider.getUsername();
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to have a default implementation of the `UsernameProvider` interface that extracts the username from the subject claim of a JWT. However, in the service that depends on the library I want to use Basic authentication, therefore I'd create a `BasicAuthUsernameProvider` that overrides `getUsername()`.

I naturally get an error when there are multiple autowire candidates of the same type (`DefaultUsernameProvider` in the library, and `BasicAuthUsernameProvider` in the service), so I'd have to mark the bean in the service as `@Primary`. But I don't want to have the library clients specify a primary bean, but instead mark a default.

Adding `@Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` on the `DefaultUsernameProvider` didn't work.

Adding `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` in a Configuration class in the library didn't work either.

**EDIT:** Turns out, adding `@Component` on the `UsernameProvider` implementation classes renders `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` useless, as Spring Boot tries to autowire every class annotated as a Component, therefore throwing the *"Multiple beans of type found"* exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the method that instantiates your bean with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`. This would mean that the method will be used to instantiate your bean only if no other `UserProvider` is declared as a bean.

In the example below you must not annotate the class `DefaultUserProvider` as `Component`, `Service` or any other bean annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class UserConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  public UserProvider provideUser() {

    return new DefaultUserProvider();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've not posted the code for `DefaultUsernameProvider` but I guess its annotated as a `@Component` so it is a candidate for auto wiring, and the same with the `BasicAuthUsernameProvider`.  If you want to control which of these is used, rather than marking them both as components, add a `@Configuration` class, and create your `UsernameProvider` bean there:

```
@Configuration
public class ProviderConfig {
    @Bean
    public UsernameProvider() {
         return new BasicAuthUsernameProvider();
    }
}
```

This bean will then be auto wired wherever its needed

Comment: So I did that. And it worked. But only because I had added `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` on the `@Bean` annotated method in the `DefaultConfiguration` class in the library. Then I removed it, and it didn't throw an exception, but it autowired the default bean in the library instead of the one in the service. Your answer helped me find a solution, but it didn't directly solve my problem. Still, thank you!